# How to crop inner (incomplete) rectangle from contours in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I have cropped the original photo to the surrounding area but it is dependent on the mouse position as well and will be different every time. Therefore I do not want a static crop of dimensions as it will vary.

The contours do not want to detect the rectangle I want because it is an incomplete rectangle since there is a cursor in the way.

Currently, my code is able to detect the contours but will only grab the outer rectangle and make a small crop.

I would like to make it detect the inner rectangle, do I have to somehow complete the rectangle first?

[Source image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCeLz.png)

[Contours detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUFu9.png)

[What I would LIKE to crop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/661ft.jpg)

[What it is currently cropping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HbHk.png)

```
import cv2
import imutils  # https://pypi.org/project/imutils/
import numpy as np
...
def crop_hover_list(cursor_coord_x, cursor_coord_y):
    img_test = cv2.imread("source.jpg")
    grayimage = cv2.cvtColor(img_test, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, mask = cv2.threshold(grayimage, 235, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    cv2.drawContours(img_test, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)

    cv2.imshow("test", img_test)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    for contour in contours:
        if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 250:
            continue
        print(list(contour))

        ext_left = tuple(contour[contour[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
        ext_right = tuple(contour[contour[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
        ext_top = tuple(contour[contour[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
        ext_bot = tuple(contour[contour[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])

        (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        cv2.rectangle(img_test, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 3)
        cv2.imshow("test", img_test)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Use the contour hierachy to filter to the contour your desire.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work the way as expected - I solved my issue by using Canny instead of a threshold, and dilating it.

Answer (score 1):

I have your test image in images/  folder. Change it as you need to test the script.

```
img_test = cv2.imread("images/MCeLz.png")
```

Please pay attention here:

```
ret ,contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours ...
```

I need 'ret' to work in my opencv version 3.2. May be you not.

**My solution** is use 2 parameters:
minimum area  as you did , and  color in a range. Then check that cursor is inside the contour.

```
import cv2
import imutils  # https://pypi.org/project/imutils/
import numpy as np


def crop_hover_list(cursor_coord_x, cursor_coord_y):

    img_test = cv2.imread("images/MCeLz.png")
    cimg = img_test.copy()

    mask = cv2.inRange(img_test, (200,200,200), (235, 235,235))
    
    cv2.imshow("test", img_test)
    cv2.imshow('mask',mask)

    ret ,contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    


    for contour in contours:

        if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 2000:
            continue

        (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        is_cursor_inside = x <= cursor_coord_x <= (x+w) and y <= cursor_coord_y <= (y+h)

        if is_cursor_inside:
            cv2.rectangle(cimg, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 4)
            cv2.drawContours(cimg, [contour], 0, (0,255,0), 3)
            crop = img_test[y:y+h,x:x+w]
            cv2.imshow("crop", crop)
            cv2.imshow("cimg", cimg)


        cv2.imshow("test", img_test)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

crop_hover_list(300, 50)
```

[image: This is the result]